# Symfony validation - only part of array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, validation

I need help with symfony validator. It is possible validate only specific values in array? For example I have array:

```
'0' => [
    'interestidKey' => true,
    'anotherInterestedKey' => 'foo'
],
'error' => [
    'errorMsg => 'not interest for me'
]
```

I need to validate this array with validator mainly value `0`. I need know if array contains '0' key and inside if is key `interestidKey` with boolean value. I always use Collection for array but it not work in this case because ofc shows me an error that `error` does not contain `interestidKey`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does your array look like in general? Is it just the 0 and the 'error' key? Or do you have any number of numeric keys plus the error key?

Comment: Any numbers key and error key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to do what you want with the shipped out of the box constraints. But you should be able to do what you want by writing your own: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html have a look at that and see if it can help you.

if you're validate you could do:

```
if(array_key_exists(0, $array)) {
    if(array_key_exists("interestid", $array[0])) {
       return true;
    }
} else {
  // do the error stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just build a loop over your array, check for the key and if it is a numeric key (or not the error key) apply your validation to the children. That would look like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'fields' => [
        // put any constraints for your objects here, keyed by field name
        'interestidKey' => new Assert\Type('bool')
    ],
    'allowExtraFields' => true // remove if you don't want to allow other fields than specified above
]);

$violations = [];
foreach($data as $key => $item) {
    if ($key != 'error') {
        $violations[$key] = $validator->validate($item, $constraint);
    }
}
```